# Why are the largest console columns not equal to the screen width divided by the font size in pixels?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Why are the console columns not equal to the screen width divided by the font size in pixels?

The code is as follows:

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    HANDLE consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX fontInfo;
    fontInfo.cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX);
    GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(consoleHandle, FALSE, &fontInfo);
    fontInfo.dwFontSize.X = (SHORT)0;
    fontInfo.dwFontSize.Y = (SHORT)10;
    fontInfo.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;
    wcscpy(fontInfo.FaceName, L"Consolas");
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(consoleHandle, FALSE, &fontInfo);

    std::cout << GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(consoleHandle).X << std::endl;

    while(1)
    {
        char a = std::cin.get();
    };
    return 0;   
}
```

My screen size is 1920x1080, so the result is 320.I think the result should be 1920/10=192.

I add some code:

```
WINBOOL Flag = SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(consoleHandle, FALSE, &fontInfo);
std::cout << Flag << std::endl; 
std::cout << "Largest:" 
          << GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(consoleHandle).X
          << std::endl;
std::cout << "real font size:"
<<(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)/GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(consoleHandle).X)
          << std::endl;
```

And the result is:

```
1
Largest:320
real font size:4
```

I expect to be able to resize the console and change its position wherever I want, and this is one of the issues I have encountered. I also want to understand why the SetConsoleWindowInfo function didn't work, but I believe I should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: The `Y` being `10` probably refers to the *height* of the font.  Not sure if that is a measure of the leading size or only the cap-height, or something in between.  If `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` fails, you should check the error code for **why** it failed.

Comment: Since Y is height, maybe height (X) is determined automatically, and ends up smaller than 10? Did you check the actual font size with your image editor?

Comment: you should also check the result of `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`

Comment: These APIs are not recommended and do not have a virtual terminal equivalent. Could you please tell us what you want to realize?

dwFontSize: A COORD structure that contains the width and height of each character in the font, in logical units. 

If you want to obtain the size of the font, pass the font index to the `GetConsoleFontSize function`.